# Killed git push process, lost all files

Tags: git

I was pushing to a git repository, when it was taking too long, and I killed it using ^C.

```
Personas-MacBook-Pro:ReCDroid personanongrata$ git push
Enumerating objects: 12911, done.
Counting objects: 100% (12911/12911), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (12413/12413), done.
^Citing objects:  16% (2192/12910), 1.34 GiB | 702.00 KiB/s      
Personas-MacBook-Pro:ReCDroid personanongrata$ git status
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729077/git-stop-git-push), it should be safe to kill a push process, but all the data has been deleted on my computer. How can I recover it?
Thanks!

Comment: What does git status say now? What does the directory contain? Are you sure this is gits fault? Perhaps an external process deleted the files in question.

Comment: you show the "git status" command but not what it returned.  Is this like a cliffhanger for next season?

Comment: I tried reverting the commit, that did nothing. I'm a dumbass, accidentally closed that terminal session so lost all output.
Now all git says 
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

 .DS_Store
 Artifact-Evaluation/
 Comparison/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
But those folders/files are only small fraction of what was there originally

Comment: Say `git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD`. Do you see all your files now?

Comment: @matt if it hangs like both his `git push` and `git status` apparently did, that's Evidence #3 for my answer.

Comment: #MrNg, it would be proper and polite to let people know how you resolved this, especially because people generously gave you their time. You do this by adding a comment, accepting an answer, or closing the question if you have given up. I hope my diagnosis was wrong (for your sake), but I I would like to know, either way.

Answer (score 1):

#### looks like file system or disk issues.

**Evidence #1: "it was taking too long"**

Why was it taking so long? Was it in fact hung? Corrupt/failing hard drive?

**Evidence #2: `git status` never returns. No error messages.**

I'm assuming the last line of your console output is `git status` with no output because it hung too.

This points to file-system level corruption or disk/SSD failure.

**Expert Witnesses**

It is highly unlikely that git could have done this.

- [Can a git repository be corrupted if a command modifying it crashes or is aborted?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8384101)
- [How can I corrupt a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19759698)
- [Repair corrupted Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8271263) (note the reported causes by the OP and commenters isn't git, but a couple of hard reboots and other things that resulted in corruption)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8104022

  > Leaving disk failure aside: no, it's not possible to corrupt a remote git repository through git commands. It's not even possible to corrupt a local git repository through git commands only – search & replace sure ain't no git command.
  >
  > You can however lose commits, by running git reset --hard, expiring the reflog and then pruning and garbage collecting the repository. But then again, this is not a corrupt git repository … it simply misses the data you removed from it …
- [How to recover corrupt git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41675560/8910547)

**Verdict**

Backup your drive and the run checks on the partition and drive. Try the solutions at the above links.